# Determination Problem (Category Theory)

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

In category **Sets**, 
$$f: A→B$$
$$h: A→C$$
Suppose,**Proposition M** is following :

for every pair of points $a_1, a_2$ of $A$, it is true that,

if $$f∘a_1=f∘a_2$$ then $$h∘a_1 = h∘a_2$$

**Proposition N** is following:

If M is True, then

there exists $g: B→C$ such that $g∘f=h$.

**Following is my attempt. Please feel free to comment not only on accuracy, but on general style like readability et cetera. Another question: Is it possible to prove it using definition of points, not considering what is in the set?**

I tried (And succeeded I think) to prove by constructing a $g:B→C$ such that $g∘f=h$ as following:

Definition 1: **Range** of mapping $f:A→B$ is range(f), a subset of B, such that for every $b \in range(f)$, there exists at least 1 $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$ and there exists no b' such that $f(a' \in A) = b' \in B$ and $b \notin range(f)$.

Definition 2: If  $f:A→B$, then **preimage** of $b \in range(f)$ is a set $P_b,_f$, a subset of $A$, such that, for every $a \in P_b,_f$, $f(a)=b$.

**Lemma 1**
For every $b \in Range(f)$, there exists $c \in Range(h)$ such that $$P_b,_f \subseteq P_c,_h$$

**Proof (Lemma 1)**

Suppose Lemma 1 is false, then that means that there exists at least 1 $b \in Range(f)$ such that there does not exist $c \in Range(h)$ such that $$P_b,_f \subseteq P_c,_h$$

Note that $|P_b,_f| > 1$. It cannot be zero, because $b \in Range(f)$. It cannot be 1 because every element of $A$ is mapped to some element of $C$ via $h$, which means that $$P_b,_f \subseteq P_c,_h$$.

Suppose $a_1, a_2 \in P_b,_f$.

According to proposition M,

if
$$f(a_1)=f(a_2)$$

then
$$h(a_1) = h(a_2)$$

Lets say

$$h(a_1) = h(a_2)=c$$

hence $a_1, a_2 \in P_c,_h$.

If $|P_b,_f|=2$, we are done because it contradicts our initial assumption that Lemma 1 is false.
If $|P_b,_f|>2$, we repeat the process by replacing $a_2$ with some other element $a_3 \in P_b,_f$, arriving at conclusion that $a_1, a_3 \in P_c,_h$. Hence, eventually, one will arrive at a contradiction. Thus, Lemma 1 is True.

**Lemma 2**
If there exists $b \in Range(f)$ such that there exists $c_1, c_2 \in Range(h)$ such that,

$P_b,_f \subseteq P_{c_1},_h$ and $P_b,_f \subseteq P_{c_2},_h$

then,

$$c_1 = c_2$$

**Proof (Lemma 2)**
Suppose, Lemma 2 is false.
Suppose $a \in P_b,_f$. Then, $ a \in P_{c_1},_h$ and $a \in P_{c_2},_h$. But, by definition of a function which has $h(a) = c_1$ and $h(a) = c_2$ does not exist. Hence, it is contradiction. Thus, lemma 1 must be true.

**Definition of g**
$$g: B \rightarrow C$$

for every $b \in range(f)$, map b to c such that $$P_b,_f \subseteq P_{c},_h$$. **Note** it does not matter that, elements that are not in $range(f)$ are mapped to what element in C.

**Corollary 1**
Proposition N is True.

**Proof (Corollary 1)**
Suppose Proposition N is False.

Then there exists $a \in A$ such that

$$g∘f(a) \ne h(a)$$

$$g(f(a)) \ne h(a)$$

Suppose $f(a) = b \in range(f)$,

$$g(b) \ne h(a)$$

Suppose $ g(b) = c_1$ and $h(a) = c_2$,

$$c_1 \ne c_2$$

Note that $ a \in P_{c_2},_h$. Hence, $a \notin P_{c_1},_h$, which contradicts definition of $g$. Hence, Corollary 1 must be True. Thus, proposition N is True.

Comment: If you're working with elements, it's simpler to just argue as follows: let $g = hf^{-1}$, where $f^{-1}:B \to A$ is any preimage function of $f$ extended to $B$ arbitrarily. By your proposition M, $g$ is well-defined, and by construction $gf = h$.

Comment: @AlexProvost,  if you are defining $f^{-1}: B→A$, then $f^{-1}$ cannot be a function. Suppose $f(a_1)=f(a_2)=b$, $f^{-1}$ takes $b$ to two elements i.e. $a_1$ and $a_2$. But, usually pre-image function is a function that is defined over powerset of A [$P(A)$], i.e. $f^{-1}: B→P(A)$.

Comment: By "any preimage function $f^{-1}$ extended to $B$ arbitrarily" I mean any function $f^{-1}:B \to A$ whose restriction to $\operatorname{im}(f) \subset B$ is a section of $f:A \to \operatorname{im}(f)$. (That is to say, $f(f^{-1}(b)) = b$ for all $b \in \operatorname{im}(f)$.) There are many such functions, but just pick any one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well then on base of:  $$\forall a,a'\in A[f(a)=f(a')\implies h(a)=h(a')]\tag1$$it must be shown that $g\circ f=h$ for some $g:B\to C$.

You can just start by "quasi-defining" function $g$ by the prescription $$f(a)\mapsto h(a)\text{ for every }a\in A\tag2$$

Then $(1)$ gives us the assurance that like this $g$ is well defined on $\text{im }f\subseteq B$.

To make it a function not only defined $\text{im }f\subseteq B$ but also on the elements of $B$ that do not belong to $\text{im }f$ pick out some $c\in C$ and complete the prescription by adding: $$b\mapsto c\text{ for every }b\in B\setminus\text{im}f$$

Now a function $g:B\to C$ is constructed that according to $(2)$ will satisfy $g\circ f=h$ as requested.

---

**Edit**

This only works if indeed some $c\in C$ does exist (ie. $C$ is not empty) or if no such $c$ is needed (which is the case if  $f$ is surjective).

This became evident by the answer of Fernando Larrain.

Comment: hope you are doing well. Please see the Answer by Fernando Larrain below. It seems that we both assumed $C \ne \emptyset$, and it seems appropriate, for the sake of readers, to either correct the answer or add a link to Fernando Larrain's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but it seems that Proposition N is not true (or there is an implicit assumption). Consider the case where $A = C = \varnothing \neq B$. Then, Proposition M would be vacuously true, but there are no maps $g$ with nonempty domain and empty codomain. Ruling out this exceptional case, though, Proposition N would hold, as you correctly showed.

Comment: First of all, thank you for pointing that out. Clearly, Proposition N would fail in the case you elaborated. I assumed $C$ to non-empty, see my note above the Corllary 1, of course, implicitly. To be honest, I was even unaware of it. drhab seems to have also assumed it when he wrote, 'pick out some $c\in C$.

Comment: @jaspreet Yes, this is correct. I have edited my answer. Thank you both.